# Проектирование базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста по следующему вопросу. Я собираюсь писать CMS, и есть вопрос касательно проектирования таблиц в базе данных.

Допустим есть таблица с полями: ID, user_logn и еще одна таблица: ID, post, user_id

Вопрос в следующем, существуют ли в mysql некие связи, чтобы, например, при удалении юзера, удалились все его посты автоматически?

Comment: Но ведь это неправильно!

Допустим этот юзер сначала писал отличные посты, потом ему надоело и он начал "халявить" и разводить нюни. Но первые посты заслуживают интереса и часто просматриваются, а ты их просто покосишь.

Comment: Да суть не в этом, суть в вопросе. Разумеется не старые посты не будут удаляться. Я имею ввиду, если, к примеру у юзера, хранятся какие-либо другие данные в других таблицах, то их и надо удалять при удалении юзера.

Comment: Тебе все равно нужно учитывать выбрать ил InnoDB или MyIsam, у них у каждой свои плюсы и минусы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть, правда не во всех типах таблиц, в InnoDB - есть, если есть желание - можно [узнать больше о Foreign Key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Плюс триггеры так-же ни кто не отменял, [узнать больше про триггеры](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

Comment: Благодарствую. То что нужно

Comment: Не забудьте принять ответ, если он Вас устраивает, заранее спасибо

Comment: спасибо, ответ принял.